# Visual Studio 2012/13 Missing MVC NuGets in Exported Template

Tags: .net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, nuget, project-template

I exported a working project template and tried creating a new project using it.

Here are the errors I am getting.

```
Type IAppBuilder is not defined.
Type CookieAuthenticationOpetions is not defined
Type OwinStartupAttribute is not defined
Type IAppBuilder is not defined
DefaultAuthenticationTypes is not declared
```

There is also 53 warnings, including

```
Could not resolve this reference...
```

My question is why aren't these being carried over? I really do not want to have to do this for every project I create from this template.

**Update**

The same thing is happening with a non-mvc template I created. I didnt even make any coding changes before exporting it.

Here are some

```
ScriptBundle is not defined
FriendlyURLSettings is not defined
BundleCollection is not defined
```

**Update 2**

The same thing is occurring in Visual Studio 2012. (updated question's title)

**Update 3**

It is showing these references in packages.config. Still not sure why they are not being referenced:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery" version="1.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.24" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="knockoutjs" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20715.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="2.0.30116.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="2.0.30116.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

No NuGets appear under All in the NuGet Manager.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Nuget related problem. Have you got VS2012 Update 3?

Please try reinstalling the Nuget Package Manager as described in this question:

[Why does NuGet fail to load in Visual Studio 2012 after updating to VS Update 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577736/why-does-nuget-fail-to-load-in-visual-studio-2012-after-updating-to-vs-update-3?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > General

Check the checkboxes for "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio".

Rebuild solution to see if the packages are being downloaded.

Hope it helps.